# End-to-"many ends" encryption for web service

Tags: encryption, web, end-to-end

I need a framework to provide an end-to-end encryption for all users on my platform. There are two types of users on my platform:

1. the ones that *publish* sensible data (call the set of users `P`)
2. the ones that want to *receive* sensible data (call the set of users `R`)

A user `p` in `P` should be able to decide whom in `R` the data should be available for (of course the data should never be available for me as a platform provider). Thus, I thought, every user in `R` gets a pair of keys and whenever `p` publishes something, the data has to be encrypted with every public key of the users in `R`, that are white-listed. This sounds solid on a theoretical level but I imagine, there are many problems that arise when implementing this.

- Every encrypted data record has to be stored on the database for every white-listed user in `R` which yields to a very large factor of storing overhead
- One has to keep track of changings `p` does to his white list
- ...

But the main question is: Are there stable solutions to provide users with a pair of keys? The only approach I found was [Web Crypto](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) which seems to be in an early development mode.

Ideas that I came up with:

1. Isn't it possible to store the encrypted private key itself on the server and provide it after standard authentication? (maybe by adding another encryption layer for the delivery)
2. It is rather not an optimal approach, but if there is no other way: Could there be a solid solution if we let the user install additional software?